# Variadic template recursion, incorrect number of arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm currently working with the C/C++ MATLAB API, and I'm attempting to use variadic template functions; I'm not very familiar with it. It would effectively output a list of data structures into a MATLAB structure.

When compiling I receive the following 2 errors:

matLink::output2': no matching overloaded function found

'void matLink::output2(mxArray *, int, const char**, const currentData &, const restData&...)': expects 5 arguments - 3 provided

```
template<typename... Data>
void matLink::output(const char* file, const char* varName, const char** label, const Data&... data) {

    mxArray * pStruct;

    // do some stuff...

    output2(pStruct, 0, label, data...); // start recursion

    // some more
}

template<typename currentData, typename... restData>
void matLink::output2(mxArray* pStruct, int index, const char** label, const currentData& current, const restData&... rest) {
    matWrite(pStruct, current, label[index], index);
    output2(pStruct, ++index, label, rest...); // both errors at this line
}

template<typename lastData>
void matLink::output2(mxArray* pStruct, int index, const char** label, const lastData& last) {
    // base case
    output2(pStruct, last, label[index], index);
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Swap the order of `output2` definitions. Closing as typo.

Comment: Swapping the output2 functions simply results in the same sets of errors, but the second error is "... expects 4 arguments - 3 provided"?

Comment: I would have expected an error earlier - a 4-argument call appears to be ambiguous. There's no reason to prefer the second overload over the first in such a call. Also, your second overload calls `output2` in a way that doesn't match either signature - which overload is that supposed to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if something like this helps:

```
template<typename... Data>
struct OutputHelper {
  static void output(mxArray* pStruct, int index, const char** label, const Data& ...) {
    // Do nothing. We'll only get here when `Data` is empty
  }
};

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
struct OutputHelper<First, Rest...> {
  static void output(mxArray* pStruct, int index, const char** label,
                     const First& first, const Rest& rest...) {
    matWrite(pStruct, first, label[index], index);
    OutputHelper<Rest...>::output(pStruct, index+1, label, rest...);
  }
};

template<typename... Data>
void matLink::output(const char* file, const char* varName, const char** label,
                     const Data&... data) {
   mxArray * pStruct;
   OutputHelper<Data...>::output(pStruct, 0, label, data...); // start recursion
}
```

Unlike function templates, class templates support partial specialization. So it's convenient to route a recursion through a class template - easier to formulate special cases when partial specialization is available.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, upon closer inspection, something much simpler should work:

```
template<typename... Data>
void matLink::output(const char* file, const char* varName, const char** label,
                     const Data&... data) {
    mxArray * pStruct;
    int index = 0;
    auto dummy = {(matWrite(pStruct, data, label[index], index), index++)...};
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/TSGYG95905)

This takes advantage of the fact that a) expressions over parameter packs can be expanded in initializer lists, and b) individual initializers in such list are guaranteed to execute in order, left to right.